# Getting blank white space to the left of content inside pre tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Everything inside the `pre` tag currently is not being aligned left. It starting from I dont know its not even middle.
How do I style the content container in the correct way?
 
I have tried a few things, but it didn't work as expected. 
Why I am getting a huge blank space to the left inside the content of the pre tag.

```css
.d-lg-block {
  display: block!important;
}

.code-examples {
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#555555, #444444);
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  zoom: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills:before,
.code-examples .nav-pills:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills li {
  display: inline;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#555555, #444444);
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  zoom: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills li a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.code-examples .nav-pills li.active a {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#222222, #444444);
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
}

.code-examples .tab-content {
  background: #333;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/*.code-examples .tab-content pre {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    left: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}*/
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="d-lg-block">
  <div id="quickstart_code_samples" class="code-examples">
    <ul class="nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a href="#curlsample" data-toggle="pill" class="active">Curl</a></li>
      <li class=""> <a href="#rubysample" data-toggle="pill" class="active">Ruby</a></li>
      <li class=""> <a href="#pythonsample" data-toggle="pill" class="active">Python</a></li>
      <li class=""> <a href="#phpsample" data-toggle="pill" class="active">Php</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <pre id="curlsample" class="tab-pane ace_editor ace-monokai ace_dark active" style="display: block;">
   slksdk
   sdflkdsfkld
   sdflksdlkf
   ldsksd
   ddsds
  </pre>
      <pre id="rubysample" class="tab-pane ace_editor ace-monokai ace_dark" style="display: none;">
   slksdk
   sdflkdsfkld
   sdflksdlkf
   ldsksd
  </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear? I don't 100% understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

It's in the middle because you have spaces there :D
It's TAB indented.

```html
<pre>
      Indented stuff
      Indented stuff
</pre>

<pre>
Aligned left
Aligned left
</pre>
```

Comment: `<pre>` elements have a default value of `pre` for the [css property `white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values). It will preserve white spaces and tabs of the original html. like Martin Zvarik said, removing the tabs will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix your code. try out this. you cant add pre. pre is use to show exact code block on screen. because of using pre tag you are getting more space in front of your list. I have added pre and div for you. use whatever you need.

```css
.d-lg-block {
  display: block!important;
}

.code-examples {
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#555555, #444444);
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  zoom: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills:before,
.code-examples .nav-pills:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills li {
  display: inline;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#555555, #444444);
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  zoom: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
}

.code-examples .nav-pills li a {
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#222222, #444444);
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
}

.code-examples .tab-content {
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="d-lg-block">
  <div id="quickstart_code_samples" class="code-examples">
    <ul class="nav-pills nav " id="myTab" role="tablist">

      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="curl-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#curlsample" role="tab" aria-controls="curlsample" aria-selected="true">Curl</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="ruby-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#rubysample" role="tab" aria-controls="rubysample" aria-selected="false">Ruby</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""> <a href="#pythonsample" data-toggle="pill" class="active">Python</a></li>
      <li class=""> <a href="#phpsample" data-toggle="pill" class="active">Php</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content col-md-12" id="myTabContent">
      <div id="curlsample" class="tab-pane fade show  ace_editor ace-monokai ace_dark active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="curl-tab">
<pre>
slksdk
sdflkdsfkld 
sdflksdlkf
ldsksd
ddsds
</pre>
      </div>
      <div id="rubysample" class="tab-pane  fade ace_editor ace-monokai ace_dark" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ruby-tab">
        slksdk sdflkdsfkld sdflksdlkf ldsksd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```